# MSVC++ 6.0: Fatal error C1509 "Too many exception handler states in function"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, code-generation, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project that uses a lot of generated files for a GUI.  After some recent updates, I get this error.  If I remove some controls (the new ones or some old ones, doesn't seem to matter which), the error goes away.  I've temporarily worked around the problem, but I'd like a more permanent solution.  I've seen mentioned on the web that there's a fix for this in VS.Net 2003, but I can't find anything for 6.0.  Does anyone know of a hotfix or service pack that fixes this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of why I became a maverick and developed [another way of programming UIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/differential-execution).

It has none of these crazy issues, automatically does dynamic changes on-the-fly, and reduces source code by a large factor.

Comment: Please clarify what, if anything, this has to do with the C1509 Error.