# MSVC++ 6.0: C1509 “Too many exception handler states in function”

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSVC++ 6.0: Fatal error C1509 “Too many exception handler states in function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049781/msvc-6-0-fatal-error-c1509-too-many-exception-handler-states-in-function)

While compiling my cpp code in visual c++ 6.0 compiler, I am getting the following error..

> MSVC++ 6.0: Fatal error C1509 “Too many exception handler states in
>   function”

I have found two solutions for this:

1. "Break the function into two or more functions containing fewer lines."
    This is not feasible in my case. Too many codes depends on it.
2. I found a hotfix for this problem, but that works for 2003 version and above.

I would be glad if you can mention some other way out for this. If there exists any patches for VC++ 6 version, please mention link for that too.
Thanks.

PS:
(I know this question has been asked before, but i couldn't find proper solution to my situation there. If i ask in that thread, i may not get reply as those threads are prettt old. So am asking in a new thread. Thanks)

Comment: I suppose upgrading to one of this century's compilers isn't an option?

Comment: This should go into the section "palliative treatment" -- MSVC6 is so notoriously bugged and non-functional that one may wonder what point there is in spending time and energy on making any given code base work in it... can't your employer shell out the extra $60 to upgrade to MSVC8 or so?

Comment: @KerrekSB: To be fair, that would be $60, plus the time needed to rewrite the code in a language that modern compilers will accept. That's still likely to be cheaper in the long term than struggling on with MSVC6, of course.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Indeed ... as Stepanov says, "Code is a liability. The more code you write, the more problems you have." I think the OP demonstrates this idea beautifully.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You can make snarky comments about "one of this century's compilers", but I just ran into this with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @ulatekh: That's a shame. I'll refrain from making snarky comments about depending on proptietry, closed-source software.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh, you can make snarky comments about that ALL day long -- I won't interfere. ;-)  (You think I WANT to use Microsoft products? Bleah.)

Comment: It might be worth linking the hotfix if that solved the issue for you personally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over this huge function? If you do then split the function into two or more subfunctions. Callers of the function will not see any difference.